# How to solve this dead lock condition in android edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have two edit text control and i want to update the second edit text value when first edit text value is entering or vice versa. For that i used `onTextChanged(..)` method but the problem is while value `updation`(not input) time it calls onTextChanged(..) method so it gives improper result..

For example :
If i enter 20 in edittext1 and  the  result on edittext2 to should be 40(Some calculation ex: Edittext1 multiply by 2).

If i enter 20 in edittext2 and  the  result on edittext1  should be 10( Some calculation ex:Edittext2 devided by 2).

Problem is: while  showing result on edittext2 its onTextChanged method is called same time it changes the edittext1's input value...

Any Solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use it by TextChangedListener and maintain two flags be it boolean or int and change the value of each flag accordingly may solve your Problem....

Best Of Luck

Answer (score 0):

You coudl have two seperate TextWatchers for your EditTexts and based on the EditText that you edit, you change the other one.